# Adding new values in Object in Typescript

Tags: arrays, json, angular, typescript

I have write the following code in Angular 2 typescript

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
   myObj:any = 
   [
      { id: 11, name: 'Mr. Nice' },
      { id: 12, name: 'Narco' },
      { id: 13, name: 'Bombasto' },
      { id: 14, name: 'Celeritas' },
      { id: 15, name: 'Magneta' },
      { id: 16, name: 'RubberMan' },
      { id: 17, name: 'Dynama' },
      { id: 18, name: 'Dr IQ' },
      { id: 19, name: 'Magma' },
      { id: 20, name: 'Tornado' }
    ];
}
```

I want to insert new object in myObj like

```
      { id: 21, name: 'Doctor Strange' },
      { id: 22, name: 'New Hero' }
```

Could anybody help me how can I do this. I have no idea about it.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push

Comment: just push it, it is in vanillajs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply Push like this :

```
this.myObj.push(      
      { id: 21, name: 'Doctor Strange' },
      { id: 22, name: 'New Hero' });
```